# No sound on VLC and default movie player

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, vlc, totem

I don't get any sound on both VLC and the default movie player on Ubuntu 14.04 while playing both video & audio. But I do get sound when playing audio files via RhythmBox, while browsing on the net and when the logging screen appear.

I've tried:

1. Installing Ubuntu restricted extras
2. Reinstall Alsa and Pulse Audio
3. Update to latest kernel
4. Disable Auto-Mute through alsamixer setting

But all were in vain!

In Alsamixer setting, pressing F6 gives me the following informations:

```
-Card: HDA Intel PCH                                  
-Chip: IDT 92HD87B1/3
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Try Shift-A, in my case it commutes the audio device.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Re-installing a package is a good start, but if often doesn't do enough to bring back all the defaults.  Try starting the package more fresh with these steps:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio indicator-sound
$ sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio indicator-sound
$ sudo alsa force-reload
$ killall pulseaudio; rm -r ~/.config/pulse/* ; rm -r ~/.pulse*; rm ~/.config/pulse
```

You may have to reboot.

Comment: Every time I upgrade Ubuntu, sound from my headless machine breaks, and this fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

Additon to

```
$ sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio indicator-sound
$ sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio indicator-sound
$ sudo alsa force-reload
$ killall pulseaudio; rm -r ~/.config/pulse/* ; rm -r ~/.pulse*; rm ~/.config/pulse
```

I applied above commands and then

```
$ vlc --reset-config --reset-plugins-cache
```

and then saved Audio Configuration as

> Tools-->Preferences-->Audio-->Pulseaudio Audio Output

It works on my 22.04.2 LTS **without reboot**

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether it will work as I have not been in this situation.

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall vlc
```